# Javascript - how to automatically post a form

Tags: javascript, post

I have a form that I would like to submit automatically on page load however it is submitting a blank form.

This is the manual code, when I click submit either yes or no is posted without a problem.

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Do You Authorize <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->clientId) ?>?</label><br />
    <input type="submit" name="authorized" value="yes">
    <input type="submit" name="authorized" value="no">
</form>
```

This is the automated code:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();">
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <label>Do You Authorize <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->clientId) ?>?</label><br />
    <input type="submit" name="authorized" value="yes">
</form>
```

The automated code is submitting perfectly, however when I dump the $_POST variable, it is empty.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `<input type="submit">` to a `<input type="hidden">`.  It may be that because no one is actually clicking the submit button, the value isn't getting passed.

Comment: Glad it worked.  If you can accept the answer that would be great :).

Comment: Accepted, as you answered so quickly, it prevented me from accepting it initially.